# Pivot tables using pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df1= df[['rsa_units','regions','ssno','veteran','pos_off_ttl','occ_ser','grade','gender','ethnicity','age','age_category','service_time','type_appt','disabled','actn_dt','nat_actn_2_3','csc_auth_12','fy']]
```

## this will produce 1.4 mil records. I've taken the first 12.

```
Eastern Region (R9),Eastern Region (R9),123456789,Non Vet,LBRER,3502,3,Male,White,43.0,Older Gen X'ers,5.0,Temporary,,2009-05-18 00:00:00,115,BDN,2009
Northern Region (R1),Northern Region (R1),234567891,Non Vet,FRSTRY TECHNCN,0462,4,Male,White,37.0,Younger Gen X'ers,7.0,Temporary,,2007-05-27 00:00:00,115,BDN,2007
Northern Region (R1),Northern Region (R1),345678912,Non Vet,FRSTRY AID,0462,3,Male,White,33.0,Younger Gen X'ers,8.0,Temporary,,2006-06-05 00:00:00,115,BDN,2006
Northern Research Station (NRS),Research & Development(RES),456789123,Non Vet,FRSTRY TECHNCN,0462,7,Male,White,37.0,Younger Gen X'ers,10.0,Term,,2006-11-26 00:00:00,702,N6M,2007
Intermountain Region (R4),Intermountain Region (R4),5678912345,Non Vet,BIOLCL SCI TECHNCN,0404,5,Male,White,45.0,Older Gen X'ers,6.0,Temporary,,2008-05-18 00:00:00,115,BWA,2008
Intermountain Region (R4),Intermountain Region (R4),678912345,Non Vet,FRSTRY AID (FIRE),0462,3,Female,White,31.0,Younger Gen X'ers,5.0,Temporary,,2009-05-10 00:00:00,115,BDN,2009
Pacific Southwest Region (R5),Pacific Southwest Region (R5),789123456,Non Vet,FRSTRY AID (FIRE),0462,3,Male,White,31.0,Younger Gen X'ers,3.0,Temporary,,2012-05-06 00:00:00,115,NAM,2012
Pacific Southwest Region (R5),Pacific Southwest Region (R5),891234567,Non Vet,FRSTRY AID (FIRE),0462,3,Male,White,31.0,Younger Gen X'ers,3.0,Temporary,,2011-06-05 00:00:00,115,BDN,2011
Intermountain Region (R4),Intermountain Region (R4),912345678,Non Vet,FRSTRY TECHNCN,0462,5,Male,White,37.0,Younger Gen X'ers,11.0,Temporary,,2006-04-30 00:00:00,115,BDN,2006
Northern Region (R1),Northern Region (R1),987654321,Non Vet,FRSTRY TECHNCN,0462,4,Male,White,37.0,Younger Gen X'ers,11.0,Temporary,,2005-04-11 00:00:00,115,BDN,2005
Southwest Region (R3),Southwest Region (R3),876543219,Non Vet,FRSTRY TECHNCN (HOTSHOT/HANDCREW),0462,4,Male,White,30.0,Gen Y Millennial,4.0,Temporary,,2013-03-24 00:00:00,115,NAM,2013
Southwest Region (R3),Southwest Region (R3),765432198,Non Vet,FRSTRY TECHNCN (RECR),0462,4,Male,White,30.0,Gen Y Millennial,5.0,Temporary,,2010-11-21 00:00:00,115,BDN,2011
```

I then filter on ['nat_actn_2_3'] for the certain hiring codes.

```
h1 = df1[df1['nat_actn_2_3'].isin(['100','101','108','170','171','115','130','140','141','190','702','703'])]
h2 = h1.sort('ssno')
h3 = h2.drop_duplicates(['ssno','actn_dt'])
```

and can look at value_counts() to see total hires by region.

```
total_newhires = h3['regions'].value_counts()
total_newhires
```

produces:

```
Out[38]:
Pacific Southwest Region (R5)      42255
Pacific Northwest Region (R6)      32081
Intermountain Region (R4)          24045
Northern Region (R1)               22822
Rocky Mountain Region (R2)         17481
Southwest Region (R3)              17305
Eastern Region (R9)                11034
Research & Development(RES)         7337
Southern Region (R8)                7288
Albuquerque Service Center(ASC)     7032
Washington Office(WO)               4837
Alaska Region (R10)                 4210
Job Corps(JC)                       4010
nda                                  438
```

I'd like to do something like in excel where I can have the ['regions'] as my row and the ['fy'] as the columns to give me a total count of numbers based off the ['ssno'] for each ['fy'].  It would also  be nice to eventually do calculations based off the numbers too, like averages and sums.

Along with looking at examples in the url:  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html, I've also tried:

```
hirestable = pivot_table(h3, values=['ethnicity', 'veteran'], rows=['regions'], cols=['fy'])
```

I'm wondering if groupby may be what I'm looking for?

Any help is appreciated.  I've spent 3 days on this and can't seem to put it together.

So based off the answer below I did a pivot using the following code:

```
h3.pivot_table(values=['ssno'], rows=['nat_actn_2_3'], cols=['fy'], aggfunc=len).
```

Which produced a somewhat decent result.  When I used 'ethnicity' or 'veteran' as a value my results came out really strange and didn't match my value counts numbers.  Not sure if the pivot eliminates duplicates or what, but it did not come out correctly.

```
ssno
fy  2005    2006    2007    2008    2009    2010    2011    2012    2013    2014    2015
nat_actn_2_3                                            
100  34  20  25  18  38  43  45  14  19  25  10
101  510     453     725     795     1029    1293    957     383     470     605     145
108  170     132     112     85  123     127     84  43  40  29  10
115  9203    8972    7946    9038    10139   10480   9211    8735    10482   11258   339
130  299     313     431     324     291     325     336     202     230     436     112
140  62  74  71  75  132     125     82  42  45  74  18
141  20  16  23  17  20  14  10  9   13  17  7
170  202     433     226     278     336     386     284     265     121     118     49
171  4771    4627    4234    4196    4470    4472    3270    3145    354     341     34
190  1   1   NaN     NaN     NaN     1   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
702  3141    3099    3429    3030    3758    3952    3813    2902    2329    2375    650
703  2280    2354    2225    2050    2260    2328    2172    2503    2649    2856    726
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
h3.pivot_table(values=['ethnicity', 'veteran'], index=['regions'], columns=['fy'], aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
```

To get counts use the `aggfunc = len`

Also your `isin` references a list of strings, but the data you provide for columns `'nat_actn_2_3'` are `int`

Try:

```
h3.pivot_table(values=['ethnicity', 'veteran'], rows=['regions'], cols=['fy'], aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
```

if you have an older version of pandas

Comment: J Bradley, this gives me the error:  TypeError: pivot_table() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'

Comment: Can you check your pandas version? Updated to use rows and cols

Comment: pd.__version__   is 0.13.1

Comment: in the latest version rows and cols generate a warning to use index and columns instead. Add the code to work with your version

Comment: Yes, using h3.pivot_table(values=['ethnicity'], rows=['regions'], cols=['fy'], aggfunc=len, fill_value=0) worked but I can't tell what it did.  What is the aggfunc=len actually counting?

Comment: It is the length of the array generated by the pivot at the intersection of the values in the row and column (for ethnicity in your example)